# php input mask for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, input, mask

I need to generate an input mask for registering users in a mysql database using php. I need to generate a primary key like "U****" where the * is a number starting in 0001. Any suggestions please?

Comment: what do you mean? Why don't you simply create ID as int with auto increment and when you wan to get the value from db add `U` to it.

Answer (score 0):

simply create table with prefix

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
prefix CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id, prefix),
```

this works for MyISAM, not InnoDB table types.

Insert query will be  like this

```
INSERT INTO tablename (prefix) VALUES ('U')
```